# Finding if a Java class is final in JNI by using reflection

Tags: java, android, reflection, java-native-interface, final

I'm trying to find if a java class is final from C++ (jni) by using reflection. So, having the next Java methods in JNI:

```
int modifiers = com.package_name.class_name.class.getModifiers();
Modifier.isFinal(mofidiers);
```

Everything works fine until calling the reflection for [`Modifier.isFinal()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Modifier.html#isFinal(int)), which reports incorrectly that a non-final class is actually final.

I've verified the Modifiers.getModifiers results, and as expected when not final it returns correctly **1**, and when final returns **17**. Yet Modifiers.IsFinal() also returns True for the "1" value result, which is public and not final.

This issue doesn't happen if Java, only in Jni. And I would prefer not to compare directly against the numeric results.

```
jboolean test(JNIEnv* env)
{
    jclass class_Modifier = env->FindClass("java/lang/reflect/Modifier");
    jmethodID method_isFinal = env->GetStaticMethodID(class_Modifier, "isFinal", "(I)Z");

    jclass class_Class = env->FindClass("java/lang/Class");
    jmethodID method_getModifiers = env->GetMethodID(class_Class, "getModifiers", "()I");

    jclass class_Test = env->FindClass("com/package_name/Test");
    jint modifiers = env->CallIntMethod(class_Test, method_getModifiers);
    return env->CallBooleanMethod(class_Modifier, method_isFinal, modifiers);
}
```

Comment: I don't see how your second `FindClass()` call can possibly have succeeded when the argument is in the wrong format. Compare the previous call. And I don't see how your `CallBooleanMethod()` call can possibly have succeeded when the method is static. You need to error-check every JNI API function you call.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that **isFinal** is a static method, so:

Replace this:

```
env->CallBooleanMethod(class_modifier, method_isFinal, modifiers)
```

By this:

```
env->CallStaticBooleanMethod(class_modifier, method_isFinal, modifiers)
```